# can you please tell me how to redirect with prestashop version 1.7?

Tags: prestashop

can you please tell me how to redirect with prestashop version 1.7?

I have a website that used to be with this link before

https://www.miosito.com/it

and I would like to direct him to

https://www.miosito.com
via htaccess
without the / it

how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how Prestashop works when you have multiple languages installed.

You must leave only one language, if you want the URL identifying the iso lang to disappear.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it is not possible to do this via htaccess? I had thought of doing so

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond%{HTTP_HOST} ^www.misito.it/it RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.misito.it/$1 [P]
#Domain: www.misito.it
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api(?:/(.*))?$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]